# what is need for localhost in socket programming as well as general application?

Tags: c++, sockets, localhost

Localhost follows the loopback mechanism.

why we have to loop back the packets to our computer itself? what is the need for that(general case and specially socket programming)?

Also kindly specify some practical applications of localhost too?

And another clarfication i need was

localhost resolves to 127.0.0.1 (most time)
myhost name say "vinoth-computer" resolves to 192.168.111.12

is 127.0.0.1 and 192.168.111.12 one and same?

Answer (score 1):

Think about next situation: you have a client and server application running on separate stations in production. But in QA or for unit testing you want to run the client and the server instances on the same station. You can put in client definitions or parameters address of server as 'localhost' or '127.0.0.1'.
Also, sometimes you want to run 2 separate processes on the same station, when by design they should be running on the same station. You can set a communication between them through sockets and use localhost on the client side part.

Answer (score 1):

Local loop back can be used for communication applications with each other. There is a lot ways to do this, but this is one of simplest.

To specify application, great example is Apache server, which by default listen on localhost as well. So when you are developing web application, you can simply use localhost or 127.0.0.1 as address in your favorite browser.

192.168.111.12 is not same as 127.0.0.1
In your case its IP which refer to your computer in your local network (behind some router). Other computers in your network can address you computer using this address.

If you want to know more, or explain something in more detail, feel free to ask.